# Using Binwalk's python api to extract files from binary

Tags: python, reverse-engineering

I am attempting to create program in python that performs a extraction (matryoshka) on a firmware file. Basically, I'd like to implement "binwalk -Me binary_file" in python using ap functionality, instead of making a subprocess call. Unfortunately, the documentation for binwalk API is sparse. Below is a snippet of code showing how I am doing it now.

```
from subprocess import call
import binwalk

for module in binwalk.scan('test.bin',signature=True,quiet=False):
    print ("%s Results:" % module.name)

for result in module.results:
    print ("\t%s    0x%.8X    %s" % (result.file.name, result.offset, result.description))

call(["binwalk","-Me","test.bin"])
```

Any suggestions would be great!!!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provided a specific question rather than asking for advice.

Comment: Thank you very much for the constructive criticism, it is very appreciated.  I am not looking for code writing services, rather I am looking for anyone with binwalk api coding expertise.  I could provide a specific code snippet if it would help things along, but i don't' know if the proper function exists to do what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than there existing a separate function for extraction, it is an argument in the scan function.

```
for module in binwalk.scan('test.bin',signature=True,quiet=False, extract=True):
    print ("%s Results:" % module.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following :

```
binwalk.scan('test.bin', signature=True,extract=True)
```

instead of  `call(["binwalk","-Me","test.bin"])`